# Dialogflow fulfilment API - first call takes much more time than subsequent requests

Tags: axios, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm developing a **Messenger** chatbot that calls 3rd party APIs to get the data. The APIs usually return data in less than 2 seconds but when I call the APIs from Dialogflow fulfillment (inline function), the first call takes more than 20 seconds to get the data, which will impact the Dialogflow 5s timeout. The subsequent requests execute in less than 2 seconds.

I use **axios** to call the APIs. Any suggestions to improve the response time?

Below is the function that calls the API

```
function getArrearsData(agent,tenantId) {
console.log("Getting the Arrears Details");

 return axios.get(`${baseUrl}api/Integrations/Arrears?tenantId=${tenantId}`)
  .then((result) => {
    if (result.data) {
      if (result.data.responseCode == 12) {
        let arrearsData = {};
        if (result.data.arrears.length > 0) {
          let paidToDate = moment(result.data.arrears[0].paidToDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
          arrearsData = {
            arrearsAmount: "$" + result.data.arrears[0].arrearsAmount,
            arrearsDays: result.data.arrears[0].arrearsDays,
            paidToDate: paidToDate
          };
        } else {
          arrearsData = {
            arrearsAmount: "N/A",
            arrearsDays: "N/A",
            paidToDate: "N/A"
          };
        }
        agent.add("");
        agent.context.set({ name: 'rental_details', lifespan: 5, parameters: { arrearsDetails: arrearsData }});
        agent.setFollowupEvent('ARREARS_DETAILS_EVENT');
      } else {
        console.log("getting arrears data failed!");
        agent.add("");
        agent.add("something wrong");
        agent.setFollowupEvent('Q_AND_A_INTENT_EVENT');
      }
    } else {
      console.log("getting arrears data failed!");
      agent.add("");
      agent.add("something wrong");
      agent.setFollowupEvent('Q_AND_A_INTENT_EVENT');
    }
  });}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that calls the API? Do you observe the same behavior if you call those APIs from outside of the fullfillment?

Comment: I would also put some timestamp logging in your fulfillment code.  I think I'd check to see if it is the start/initiation of the fulfillment function that is taking long or is it the first call to your back-end service that is taking a long time.  If the later, then it might not be a Google issue but the back-end service provider you are calling.

Comment: I suggest implementing logging as Kolban said to narrow down the location of the issue and kindly sharing the results with us